# Difference between use of "ephemeral" and "transient"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

What are some differences between the ways/contexts in which one would use "ephemeral" versus "transient", and vice versa?

Comment: Something *ephemeral* does not last long.  Something *transient* is in a state of transition.

Answer (score 12):

Both refer to short-lived things or activities or events.  *Transient* implies some kind of transition between states in which the transient state does not last very long.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that while "ephemeral" definitely means that lasts very little, "transient" can also take the hue of something transitory. And, sometimes, "transitory" things do become permanent :-)

Something ephemeral is, instead, going to die (soon) in any case. Sometimes lasting only one day, like the mayfly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayfly